# How do I run a single integration test in grails 3?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, automated-tests

Grails 3 (at least 3.1.10) is flaky in running only specific tests. How do I get it to run a single integration test?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a sample command to run a single integration test

```
grails test-app *LoginFunctional* -integration
```

If you put -integration flag before pattern, the test-app command will ignore the pattern and execute all integration tests.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy lately.  Thank you.

Comment: Beware that left wildcard expands to a full package path, e.g. **com.my.package**.LoginFunctionalTest

Answer (score 2):

The official command line syntax is `grails test-app`, optionally followed by a pattern to match the full namespaced class name of what you want to test such as `org.myorg.ClassToTest` or `org.**.*`, and `-unit` or `-integration` to select a specific phase. See the [docs](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.10/guide/testing.html).

There are a number of quirks in Grails 3.1.10, though.

1) `grails test-app` won't always run the tests, probably a bug in the dependency management. If you first remove the test report at `build/reports/tests/index.html` grails will see that it actually needs to do something to generate a new report.

2) Sometimes things just go randomly weird. If so, do `grails clean; grails test clean`. (I didn't yet figure out if you really need both of them or only one of the two.)

3) The official way should work, but do (2) first if it doesn't. Also, if you want to run only a specific integration test you need to add `-integration` or you'll get an error. I think without such a flag Grails unconditionally first tries to run unit tests and then integration tests, and if your test pattern does not match any unit tests grails will error out. Similarly if the pattern only matches unit tests add `-unit` or you'll get an error, though you still get the correct test report in this case.

4) There's also an alternative way, by using the `-Dtest.single=<classname>` flag. This sets a system property that is picked up by gradle. I only got it working properly if I also added a `-unit` flag, but I didn't investigate very deep.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use annotation `@IgnoreRest`. Remember to `import spock.lang.IgnoreRest` and run test on specified class.