# Running a single integration test/ single test class

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I was trying to run a single test or a single class from the grails cli, but no matter what I tried I am unable to find out how to do that. Does anyone of you have an idea what could be the command for doing that?

**What I tried so far**

- `test-app -integration -Dtest.single=package.ClassSpec`: still runs all of the tests. Replacing package with a wildcard doesnt change anything.
- `test-app *ClassSpec* -integration`: runs 10 actionable tasks, not entirely sure which tests are these, the class doesnt have 10 tests.

I am using Grails 3.3.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772083/how-do-i-run-a-single-integration-test-in-grails-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./grailsw test-app MyClass`

(without Spec or Test at the end)

http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Command%20Line/test-app.html

Comment: I have combined my second bullet point with suggestion from this answer `test-app *Class* -integration` (without spec or test at the end)